# How to save one row's data to the server after inline editing in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i have seen almost all the examples and answers by @Oleg out there, haven't really found a solution yet. Here is my Grid-

```
 $(grid).jqGrid({
                 datatype: 'local', 
                 mtype: 'GET',
                 url: "/Views/MyUrl",
                 editUrl: "/Views/MyEditUrl",
                 colNames: colNames,
                 colModel: colModel,
                 altRows: false,
                 pager: $(pager),
                 loadonce: true,
                 sortable: true,
                 multiselect: false,
                 viewrecords: true,
                 shrinkToFit: false,                    
                 gridView: true
                // onSelectRow: editRow   
             }).navGrid(pager, { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false} 

             $grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', pager, {
                 edit: true,
                 add: true,
                 del: true,
                 cancel: true,
                 save: true,                    
                 editParams: {
                     keys: false
                 },
                 addParams: {
                     keys: true
                 }
             });
```

I am using **jqGrid 4.6 version, and inline row editing.**
I tried 'onselectRow' in which i called the 'saveRow' instead of 'restoreRow' , that didn't work either.
 After i edit the row, i would like to send the whole row data back to the controller to update in the database. Right now, it doesn't even hit the controller method.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. The options `editUrl` and `gridView` will be ignored, because jqGrid knows only `editurl` and `gridview: true`. You use `inlineNav` which creates "Save" and "Cancel" buttons in the navigation bar. If the user clicks on "Save" button then `saveRow` will be called. If the user clicks on "Cancel" button then `restoreRow` be called. No additional code inside of `onSelectRow` is required.

Comment: @Oleg, i completely ignored editUrl casing. :( Yes, you are right about using inlineNav. changed it to 'editurl' and now i can see it hits the method in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

See the link in 
 [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing)

You have to save the data on the function oneditfunc callback

```
 $(grid).jqGrid({
...
   onSelectRow: function(id){
     if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
        jQuery('#grid_id').restoreRow(lastSel); 
        lastSel=id; 
     }
     $(grid).jqGrid('editRow',rowid, 
   { 
        keys : true, 
       oneditfunc: function() {
       alert('Edit Complete');

      },
 beforeSaveRow: function (o, rowid) {
    // this is where you should save the data
    // Do validation and save the data here
    // Note, the 'beforeSaveRow' is undocumented, but it gets invoked before jqGrid calls its own SaveRow method.       
   // Get data by rowid and save it to DB and then 

    grid.saveRow(rowid, false);
    return false;// To avoid jqgrid from invoking its own save again
   },
 aftersavefunc: function (rowid) {
    // this fired is after saving
    var rowData = $this.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
  }
   },
...
});
```